# Example of Non-Compact Closed Set contained in Open Set With Special Property

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

I am looking for an example of an open set $A$ in a metric space $X$ and a closed, non-compact subset $B$ of $A$ such that there is no $\delta > 0$ s.t. $\{x: \textrm{dist}(x,B) < \delta\} \subset A$.

I have tried using the discrete metric and other obvious tricks but have been unable to come up with an example. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X= \Bbb R^2.$  Let $A=\{(x, y)~|~ y \gt 0 \}.$  Let $B=\{(x, y)~|x \gt 0 \land xy \geq 1 \}.$

Choose $\delta \gt 0$.  Then $(2\delta, \frac{1}{2\delta}) \in B$, so $(2\delta, -\frac{1}{4\delta}) \notin A$ but $\operatorname{dist}((2\delta, -\frac{1}{4\delta}), B) \leq \frac{3\delta}{4} \lt \delta.$

Comment: +1...... To the proposer:  Suppose $A$ and $C$ are disjoint non-empty closed subsets of  $X$ such that for every $n\in \Bbb N$ there exist $a_n\in A$ and $c_n\in C$ with $d(a_n,c_n)<1/n...$ (Neither sequence $(a_n)_n,\, (c_n)_n$ can have a convergent sub-sequence, else it would converge to a member of $A\cap C.$ ).... And let $B=X\setminus C$... An example obtained by this method  is $X=\Bbb R^2, \,A=\Bbb R\times \{0\},  \,C=\{(x,1/x):x\in \Bbb R^+\},\,B=X\setminus C.$